# Set label in popup menu - no hovering

Tags: python, menu, pygtk

Can I set a label (text) in popup menu (gtk.Menu) but without hovering effect, for example:

```
LABEL
MenuItem1 (hover effect)
MenuItem2 (hover effect)
MenuItem3 (hover effect)
```

EDIT:

[image: pygtk menu]

This is not popup menu example but it show hover effect.

For hovering effect I mean when I click left button mouse it will open the popup menu. In this menu there are couple option (like in real one: edit, paste, copy, properties). When I move mouse pointer to each item in this menu it will change background one item to other color. Like at the image.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "hovering effect"?

Comment: Also, please describe your objective (so as to why you don't want the hover effect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Widget.set_sensitive(False)](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-sensitive) to disable the menu item. This way, no *hover effect* is generated, but the menu item won't be clickable also.